# vba excel inputbox cancel exiting loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few problems with the cancel button of `application.inputbox`, it seems to be a problem with which a lot of people have to deal with but I haven't really managed too adapt the various solutions to my case.
What I would like to is to have an "infinite" loop that asks the user to input a number until he presses cancel on the inputbox.

To explain the situation a little the loop should ask for the consumption for this month and then write the month in cell A1 and the consumption in B1, then ask for the consumption for the previous month and write it underneath and so on until the user finishes the data to input and presses cancel, but if you press cancel my code will just write FALSE and keep running despite the `Data = "FALSE"` check.
Many solutions I found online don't work because I need the program to accept 0 as a number, refuse anything that is not a number and keep asking on the same month if ok is pressed without anything inside.

```
Dim Data
Dim i As Integer, Years As Integer, MonthNum As Integer, LastRow As Integer

i = 2
Do While i <= 10
    MonthNum = Month(DateAdd("m", -i + 1, Date))    'calculates month
    Years = year(DateAdd("m", -i + 1, Date))        'calculates year
    Data = Application.InputBox("Please enter consumption of " & vbNewLine _
        & MonthNum & "." & Years, "Imput Consumtion", Type:=1)
    If Data = "FALSE" Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        Cells(i, 1) = MonthName(MonthNum, 1) & " " & Years
        Cells(i, 2) = Data
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
LastRow = Range("A:A").Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(LastRow, 2)).Clear
```

I'm using `application.inputbox` because I thought it would work better (I tried using `Type:=1 + 2` and `Type:=1 + 8` to solve the problem but got no useful results) but if there is a way to do it with the regular inputbox I'm obviously ok with that.
The `While i <= 0` condition is just to stop the loop from going on forever, in my final code I would put there what ever condition I need to exit.

Any suggestinos? thanks everybody!

Comment: Your case is inconsistent, try `If Data = "False" Then`

Comment: `If CStr(Data) = CStr(False) Then` or `If TypeName(Data) = "Boolean" And Data = False Then`

Comment: I deleted my answer. Stick with what @brettdj suggested.

Comment: @brettdj this works great! if you write it into an answer I'll mark it as such... but can you explain how it works? I don't really see such a difference from what I originally did and still it makes a huge difference!

Comment: False has a value equal to 0. And hence it was exiting the loop in my code.  `Data = "False"` or `Ucase(Data)= "FALSE"` is just another way of saying the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in VBA 0 = False and there is no `==`or `===` comparator. So you can't differ between 0 and False in direct comparison.

`If Data = "False" Then` will convert `Data` to String and compare then. If Data is 0 then it compares "0" with "False" and if Data is False then it compares "False" with "False". So this works with English Excel versions.

`If CStr(Data) = CStr(False) Then` or `If TypeName(Data) = "Boolean" And Data = False Then` will be locale independent.